# Magento2 PHPUnit internal method getCollectionMock. Bug or Feature?

Tags: collection, magento2, phpunit

When I was writing unit tests for one magento collection I faced with the following strange thing:

Magento allows create mock for collection with it's internal phpunit method:

> \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager

```
public function getCollectionMock($className, array $data)
{
    if (!is_subclass_of($className, '\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection')) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            $className . ' does not instance of \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection'
        );
    }
    $mock = $this->_testObject->getMock($className, [], [], '', false, false);
    $iterator = new \ArrayIterator($data);
    $mock->expects(
        $this->_testObject->any()
    )->method(
        'getIterator'
    )->will(
        $this->_testObject->returnValue($iterator)
    );
    return $mock;
}
```

The problem appear when I'm trying to create Mock of `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`.

As you can see magento checks if described class is subclass of `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`. Not `instance of`!

Magento returns the described collection here:

```
$product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

### The question is: is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2):

You can always submit a pull request to fix the grammar here if nothing else! `$className . ' does not instance of \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection'`.

I cannot think of any reason why it is seeing if subclass (child) vs instance of (current class or child). I mean you cannot use instanceof because it requires an instance of the class (is_subclass_of() above is working on the class name in a string, which instanceof does not support).

Most likely when written they did not have a need for class or descendant. You could try for a pull request of checking for is_subclass_of() or equality (same class name).